# How to use not() selector in jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Below is html

```
<div class="radio_tab"><span>Ad View</span>
    <ul>
        <li>Ad View</li>
        <li>Page View</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My javascript is

```
$("div").not('.radio_tab').click(function(){
        alert('hi');

});
```

and also i tried

```
$("div:not(.radio_tab)").click(function(){
        alert('hi');

});
```

I am showing dropdown on click of span and it will hide on clicking on span/ul.
But problem is, i want to hide dropdown onclicking outside div.radio_tab.

I appreciate all your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those selectors will find *all* `div`s that do not have the class `radio_tab`, and apply click handlers to them. That's probably amazingly inefficient, on top of not being what you want to do. The thing it seems like you're trying to do (`$("*:not('div.radio_tab')")`) would be even worse.

One alternate approach might be to apply a click handler to the body of the document, and test the event's target to see whether it's `div.radio_tab`, or one of its children. If not, then hide the div and unbind the event handler. Something along these lines (code written here, and not tested!):

```
// attach the event handler to the body, where it will hear about
// any clicks that don't have default behavior (like links);
// use a namespaced event, so that it can be easily removed
$(document.body).bind("click.radio_tab",function(evt){
  // make sure the click is outside the div in question
  if( $(evt.target).closest("div.radio_tab").length === 0 ) {
    // hide the div, or whatever else needs to be done
    $("div.radio_tab").hide();
    // unbind the event, since it's no longer needed
    $(this).unbind("click.radio_tab");
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you elaborate more. I tried this 

$('*').click(function(){ if(!$(this).parents('div:eq(0)').hasClass("radio_tab")) alert('hi'); });

Problem in this is, it travels till root tag.

Comment: That right there is a terrible idea: you've attached an event handler to *every element in your document*. What I was proposing was taking advantage of the bubbling of events to add a single event handler to the body. I'll edit my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

since you are checking the class use **hasClass** instead to get the boolean answer:

```
($("div").hasClass("radio_tab"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handle a similar situation:

```
jQuery('div').click(function () {
    if (! (jQuery(this).hasClass('radio_tab'))) {
        /* do something */
    };
```

Here is exactly how I handle this on my site www.ipreferjim.com:

```
jQuery('div.nav_link').click(function () {
    if (! (jQuery(this).hasClass('no_select'))) {
        jQuery('div.nav_link').not(this).find('div.top_level').removeClass('nav_selected');
        jQuery(this).find('div.top_level').addClass('nav_selected');
    };
});
/* end div.nav_link .click */

jQuery('div.nav_link').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('div.top_level').fadeOut(100);
    jQuery(this).find('div.top_level').fadeIn(300);
    /* Show Sub-menu */
    jQuery(this).find('.sub_level').show();
},
function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.sub_level').hide();
});
/* end 'div.nav_link' .hover */

jQuery('div.sub_level a.dialog_link').click(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('get_json')) {
        var json_link = 'retrieve.php?type=example&short_name=' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + '&format=json';
        jQuery.getJSON(json_link, function (json) {
            jQuery('.ui-dialog-title').text(json.title);
            jQuery('.ui-dialog-content').html(json.html);
        });

        jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open');

        return false;
    };
    /* end if */
});
/* end div.sub_level a.dialog_link .click */
```

Then, my links are set up using div elements with nested unordered lists.

```
<div class="nav_link"> 
 <div class="top_level">Code</div><!-- end top_level --> 
   <div class="sub_level ui-corner-bottom"> 
     <ul id="links"> 
       <li><a href="?contentlink=assignments.php" id="assignments.php" class="navigation underline" onclick="javascript:showContent(this,'assignments.php')">Assignments</a>
       </li> 
       <li>Snippets</li> 
     </ul> 
    </div><!-- end sub_level --> 
  </div><!-- end nav_link -->
```

It seems to be a very similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. problem is i can't $('div'), because tag can be other than Div.

Comment: I edited my comment to show how I do this.  You can add the same class to both your div and span elements if you want them to have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the not selector in this case is if you have your `radio_tab` wrapped with another `div` it will stop working completely because the wrapping div doesn't have the `radio_tab` class... so either make sure there is no wrapping div and use Jim's answer or try something similar to this (but this answer could be way out in left field)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="not_radio_tab"><input type="text" readonly value="Not Ad View" />
  <ul>
   <li>Not Ad View</li>
   <li>Not Page View</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="radio_tab"><input type="text" readonly value="Ad View" />
  <ul>
   <li>Ad View</li>
   <li>Page View</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.radio_tab input')
  .focus(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('ul').css('background-color','#fc0')
  })
  .blur(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('ul').css('background-color','#222')
  });
})
```